# How can adjust images overlay size relative to img size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to set a overlay on my images and when I hover the image an overlay appears on the image and is the same size as image. When I resize the window the overlay should resize automatically.

I have tried some JS code but does not work. It's always set width/height to 0px.

Please let me know how I can fix this.

```js
var portImg = document.getElementById("portimg");
var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");
var overlayh = overlay.style.height = portImg.clientHeight;
var overlayw = overlay.style.width = portImg.clientWidth;
/*
tried this 1 too

clientHeight + "px";
clientWidth + "px";
*/
```

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  width=100%
}

.img-container img {
  width=100%
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay:hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: .95;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
  <!-- overlay continer -->

  <div class="img-container">
    <img id="portimg" src="images/port.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- img container -->
</div>
<!-- col -->
```

Comment: What are you overlaying?

Comment: on Image. where whenever i move my mouse on desired img. samples is written above.

Comment: **What** are you wanting to overlay? Text? Another image?

Comment: here is the screenshot. 
http://prntscr.com/eh84v6

Comment: So you want to overlay additional content. **Michael Coker** has provided you an answer that is very close to what you would need to do. If you get a bit more specific on requirements I'm sure he'll update his answer to more closely reflect them.

Comment: yes I commented on his answer. waiting for his reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an overlay with CSS alone using either your own element or a pseudo element. Use `absolute` positioning on the overlay with `relative` positioning on the parent, and the overlay will scale automatically with the parent.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.img-container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="portimg" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="">
  <div class="overlay">overlay</div>
</div>
```

If you still want to have the overlay's width and height be controlled via javascript, I would create a function that matches the heights and call that on page load as well as on the `window`'s `resize` event.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  /* right: 0; bottom: 0; */
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.img-container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="portimg" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="">
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">overlay</div>
</div>

<script>
  function matchHeight() {
  var img = document.getElementById('portimg'),
      overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  overlay.style.width = img.offsetWidth + 'px';
  overlay.style.height = img.offsetHeight + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  matchHeight();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  matchHeight();
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP would like to overlay content (per comments to question). Perhaps you could update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @FaisalImran like I mentioned, you can use the pseudo element or a normal element. Just added a normal element to the html (`div.overlay`) and changed the pseudo element selectors in the CSS to reflect the new element.

Comment: @MichaelCoker
Thanks sir. this is useful. but this thread is related to JavaScript if you could provide JavaScript code.

Comment: @FaisalImran what is the requirement for JavaScript? Just to see how it's done in JS? If what you need can be accomplished via CSS then go that route. Especially when the CSS is a lot less involved than the JS counterpart.

Comment: @FaisalImran no problem. just updated my answer with a JS solution. I don't know why you would ever do that when you can just use CSS. JS will be far less performant as it has to manually set the height/width, and you fire that manual work with every resize on the window, which is not performant at all.

Comment: Thanks Bro. I am just learning JS so i wanted to know how can we do this.
Actually i did not call function on load that was the problem..

Bundle of thanks :))